# eth.syncing is falling behind

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes, full-node

I lost internet connection for about 5 minutes and my full node was disconnected. At first it was about 500 blocks behind and looked like it was catching up. Now every time I check:

```
eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
```

it looks like it is falling farther and farther behind (currently the output is over 3000 blocks).

Answer (score 2):

I believe something got corrupted when I lost connection. I resynced from scratch and everything has been working fine. I have even cleanly exited and restarted my node and it catches back up fast now.